# My Minecraft Native Launcher Won't Download

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-10, minecraft-launcher

I downloaded the Minecraft setup thing but when I click on it, it shows "downloading native launcher" but then it reaches a certain point then it stops downloading. I've tried uninstalling the setup thing but it still doesn't work. Plz help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was on mine Windows 8.1 computer. I **updated my Java**, reinstalled Minecraft (don't think that was the problem) and **scanned my computer for viruses** (especially those that block some .exe files). The scan was positive - found something - all viruses were deleted.
Then it worked fine. If this doesn't help you you could also try going to a friend (to another Wi-Fi), **maybe your firewall blocks the download.**

Comment: if all of the above don't work, try using one of the other launchers the minecraft website provides.